# Why does squaring columns produces different answers

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2016 and I noticed that using 3 different methods of squaring a column results in 3 different answers.

Formula `POWER(G3:G4995,2)` produces 1121.701069

Formula `(G3:G4995)^2` produces 1121.566637

Formula `(G3:G4995)*(G3:G4995)` produces 1121.57079

Why do I get three different answers?

Comment: Are you wrapping it in something like SUM or SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: Maybe it is a case of [floating point precision error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result).

Comment: @Scott Craner No, I used the formulas as stated.

Comment: Then you are not trully returning the array.  Try all three wrapped in SUMPRODUCT: `SUMPRODUCT((G3:G4995)^2)`...

Comment: So wrapping it in SUMPRODUCT gives me the same answer for all three. What do the original formulas return then?

Comment: you should be able to use Formulas→Evaluate Formula to see what is happening. But mainly you are returning an array and only seeing the first one.

Comment: What *exactly* is in G3?